# If $f\star g=\mathcal{O}$ then $f=\mathcal{O}$ or $g=\mathcal{O}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\Bbb{F}$ is an arbitrary field. It can be proved that the set of all functions from $\Bbb{F}$ to $\Bbb{F}$, denoted by $\mathcal{F}(\Bbb{F},\Bbb{F})$, is a vector space over $\Bbb{F}$ with addition $\oplus$ and scalar multiplication $\ast$ defined as follows

$$\begin{align}
(f \oplus g)(x) &= f(x)+g(x), & \forall x \in \Bbb{F}\\
(\lambda \ast f)(x)&=\lambda \cdot f(x), & \forall x \in \Bbb{F}
\end{align}$$

with $\lambda \in \Bbb{F}$, $f,g \in \mathcal{F}(\Bbb{F},\Bbb{F})$, $+$ and $\cdot$ being addition and multiplication on $\Bbb{F}$. The function $\mathcal{O}:\Bbb{F} \to \Bbb{F}$ is defined to be a function that takes every element in $\Bbb{F}$ to the additive identity of the $\Bbb{F}$, namely $0$, i.e.,

$$\begin{align} 
\mathcal{O}:&\Bbb{F} \to \Bbb{F} \\
&x \to 0
\end{align}$$

It can be verified that $\mathcal{O}$ is the additive identity of $\mathcal{F}(\Bbb{F},\Bbb{F})$. Suppose, we define a product between two elements of $\mathcal{F}(\Bbb{F},\Bbb{F})$ as follows

$$\begin{align}
(f \star g)(x) &= f(x) \cdot g(x), & \forall x \in \Bbb{F}
\end{align}$$

**Question**

Is the following theorem true in general? If **not**, what are the weakest assumptions needed to make it true? You can have further assumptions on $f$, $g$.

> **Theorem**. If $f\star g=\mathcal{O}$ then $f=\mathcal{O}$ or $g=\mathcal{O}$.

---

**My Thought**

First I translated the theorem according to definitions as

If $f(x) \cdot g(x) = 0, \forall x \in \Bbb{F}$ then $f(x)=0, \forall x \in \Bbb{F}$ or $g(x)=0, \forall x \in \Bbb{F}$.

then I assumed that the negation is true to reach a contradiction. So I wrote

$\exists x_1 \in \Bbb{F}: f(x_1) \ne 0$ and $\exists x_2 \in \Bbb{F}: g(x_2) \ne 0$ and $f(x) \cdot g(x) = 0, \forall x \in \Bbb{F}$

but this will just imply that $g(x_1)=0$,$f(x_2)=0$. So the negation can be true too! However, if I could prove that

$\exists x_0 \in \Bbb{F}: f(x_0) \ne 0$ and $\exists x_0 \in \Bbb{F}: g(x_0) \ne 0$

that could do the job but I don't know how to prove this! More assumptions on $f$ and $g$ are needed. But what are they?

Comment: this "theorem" is blatantly false. But since you can make more assumptions on $f$ and $g$ you can just assume that $f= \mathcal O$ and then it becomes true.

Comment: Assume $|D|=1$ ...

Comment: @H.R. For any $D$ with more than 1 element, the statement is wrong

Comment: @user251257: I don't think so! :) If $D=\Bbb{F}=\Bbb{R}$ and $f$ and $g$ are continuous then it is right! :)

Comment: @H.R. Nope ${}{}{}$

Comment: @H.R. Polynomials would work.

Comment: @H.R. Think of hat / triangle functions. What kind of additional assumption have you in mind? Otherwise it is way too broad.

Comment: @H.R. Rings of polynomials are integral domains if the coefficients come from an integral domain. And a field is obviously a integral domain.

Comment: @user251257: Can you kindly write an answer and discuss the polynomial case. Also I don't know too much about abstract algebra so I removed the tag. In fact, I am not familiar with rings and integral domain. Please write an answer that I can understand by just knowing the definitions and properties of field, vector-spaces and functions. :) you can also assume $D=\Bbb{F}$ in your answer. :)

Comment: @mercio: Would you please take a look at the question again. :) I changed it a little by adding some more specifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need additional assumptions. Take for example, in the real numbers, the function $f$ that is zero everything with the exception of $f(0)=1$ and take $g$ to be $1$ everywhere with the exception of $g(0)=0$. Neither of these functions are identically zero, but $f(x)g(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Basically, $f \star g = \mathcal{O}$, then for each $x$ we have $f(x) \cdot g(x)=0$ and since the real numbers are an integral domain, either $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$. So at each $x$ we have a zero at least for one function and since there are infinitely many $x$'s, there are infinitely many zeroes between the two functions. However, the only polynomial with infinitely many zeroes is the $\mathcal{O}$ polynomial (all other polynomials of degree $n$ have at most $n$ real zeroes). Of course, all this is in the real numbers and not general fields.

Comment: It seems if $f$ and $g$ are polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{F}$ then the theorem is true! :) However, I don't know why!?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my previous comment which I deleted. Basically, $fg = \mathcal{O}$, then for each $x$ we have $f(x)g(x) = 0$ and since the real numbers are an integral domain, either $f(x)=0$ or $g(x)=0$. So at each $x$ we have a zero at least one function and since there are infinitely many $x$'s, there are infinitely many zeroes between the two functions. However, the only polynomial with infinitely many zeroes is the 0 polynomial (all other polynomials of degree $n$ have at most $n$ real zeroes). Of course, all this is in the real numbers and not general fields.

Comment: Does this hold for complex field too? :) I think the answer should be yes.